# R dataframe: select rows by sorting one column and based on values in two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe `df` as below:

```
user_id     rating      date          status
10506       4           2008-11-11    2
10506       3           2008-11-13    1
10506       4           2008-11-23    3
10506       2           2008-11-29    4
10506       1           2009-01-15    3
10506       1           2009-11-11    2
10507       3           2007-10-20    1
10507       5           2007-11-11    1
10507       2           2007-12-21    2
10507       5           2008-01-08    3
10507       4           2008-01-31    3
10507       3           2008-02-05    4
10507       4           2008-03-10    2
```

I would like to do the following two operations:

1. Select three rows for each `user_id` with the earliest `date`. I know that all `user_id` have at least three observations. `date` is not in date format, but when I order by `date`, I am able to get in chronological order.
2. Select three rows for each `user_id` with earliest `date` where `status` is 3 or 4.

Is there any `dplyr` solution where I can group by `user_id` and then select first three rows after sorting `date` in ascending order? Any help is appreciated.

Edits:

I corrected a typo in dummy data I provided in the question. Apologies for making this error. Also, including an expected output to make things clear:

Output for part 1:

```
user_id     rating      date          status
10506       4           2008-11-11    2
10506       3           2008-11-13    1
10506       4           2008-11-23    3
10507       3           2007-10-20    1
10507       5           2007-11-11    1
10507       2           2007-12-21    2
```

Output for part 2:

```
user_id     rating      date          status
10506       4           2008-11-23    3
10506       2           2008-11-29    4
10506       1           2009-01-15    3
10507       5           2008-01-08    3
10507       4           2008-01-31    3
10507       3           2008-02-05    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You know how to conduct `group_by(user_id)` and `arrange(date)`

   - I think in your procedure, it is okay to do `filter(status == 3 | status == 4)` first
   - to subset `status` which is 3 or 4 first
2. Now you have

   1. for each `user_id`:
   2. `date` is arranged,
   3. and `status` is 3 or 4
   4. Hence, you just simply `slice(1:3)`: subset *first three rows for each group*

Using `%>%` sequentially, you can easily get the result.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tribble(
    ~user_id, ~rating, ~date, ~status,
    10506, 4, "2008-11-11", 2,
    10506, 3, "2008-11-13", 1,
    10506, 4, "2008-11-23", 3,
    10506, 2, "2008-11-29", 4,
    10506, 1, "2009-01-15", 3,
    10506, 1, "2009-11-11", 2,
    10507, 3, "2007-10-20", 1,
    10507, 5, "2007-11-11", 1,
    10507, 2, "2007-12-21", 2,
    10507, 5, "2008-01-08", 3,
    10507, 4, "2008-01-31", 3,
    10507, 3, "2008-02-05", 4,
    10507, 4, "2008-03-10", 2
  )

# dplyr solution
df %>%
  filter(status == 3 | status == 4) %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  slice(1:3)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   user_id [2]
#>   user_id rating date       status
#>     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1   10506      4 2008-11-23      3
#> 2   10506      2 2008-11-29      4
#> 3   10506      1 2009-01-15      3
#> 4   10507      5 2008-01-08      3
#> 5   10507      4 2008-01-31      3
#> 6   10507      3 2008-02-05      4
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tribble(
~user_id, ~rating,  ~date,  ~status,
10506, 4, "2008-11-11",    2,
10506, 3, "2008-11-13",    1,
10506, 4, "2008-11-23",    3,
10506, 2, "2008-11-29",    4,
10506, 1, "2009-01-15",    3,
10506, 1, "2009-11-11",    2,
10507, 3, "2007-10-20",    1,
10507, 5, "2007-11-11",    1,
10507, 2, "2007-12-21",    2,
10507, 5, "2008-01-08",    3,
10507, 4, "2008-01-31",    3,
10507, 3, "2008-02-05",    4,
10507, 4, "2008-03-10",    2
)

Part1<- df %>% 
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  arrange(date,.by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(seq=row_number()) %>%
  filter(seq <=3) %>%
  select(-seq)


Part2<- df %>% 
  filter(status %in% c(3,4)) %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  arrange(date,.by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(seq=row_number()) %>%
  filter(seq <=3) %>%
  select(-seq)
```